# colab open csv with built in function

Tags: python, csv, google-colaboratory

I want to open a github raw CSV file with the Python built-in open() function but I am getting a [Errno 2] No such file or directory error:

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com//snowformatics//Bioinformatics//master//python_course092021//test_data//test.csv'

data = open(url, 'r')
```

With Pandas everything works:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(url)
```

I want to avoid Pandas or urlopen because I am using it for a  course and want to stick to built-in open() function. Any way to open an url with the Python built-in open() function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it's a built-in library.

NOTE: you cant use `open` to access web-data

```py
import urllib.request

file_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com//snowformatics//Bioinformatics//master//python_course092021//test_data//test.csv'

file_name = 'test.csv'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(file_url, file_name)
```

Comment: I want to use the Python built-in open() function, thanks.

Comment: `urllib` is part of the standard Python library and does not require any separate installation of a third-party package. There is no reason not to use it.